# Maximum Recurring plans allowed by PayPal rest-api-sdk-.net

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi i have a question regarding recurring plans.

Can i create a unique plan for each of my customer? Does Paypal restrict the maximum number of plans that can be created ?

I want a customized recurring billing plan for each of my customer. Is this possible ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same question - I want to create a 1:1 relationship of plans to customers.

Comment: There is no limit to the plans that you can create with paypal.